# How to make non table pagination with Buefy

Tags: vue.js, pagination, buefy

I wish to make pagination for my class project, currently using Vue.js and Bulma + Buefy.
I have an array of objects and I want to display 5 per page.
Already have the layout done and everything, I just want to know how to make the pagination work. Sorry can't post the code because it's not displaying correctly in here but I'm using v-for to display each iteration.
Much thanks!

Comment: Without code sample it's hard to say. You need to go to [tables documentation](https://buefy.github.io/documentation/table), section **Pagination and sorting**. For the each example on the page, in the top right corner you can click on the **CodePen** link, which will show how that example was implemented. [Here is the CodePen example for pagination](https://codepen.io/pen?editors=1010)

Comment: Could be as easy as adding `paginated` to your `<b-table paginated ...`

Comment: But I don't want to use b-table. I'm using my own layout which is similar to the one on here, Stack Overflow.

Comment: You can use [<b-pagination>](https://buefy.github.io/documentation/pagination), but without any code example, it's impossible to provide any code example for your problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `<b-pagination>` component

Without any code sample from you, this would be minimal approach to use that component

```js
const example = {
    data() {
        return {
            items: [],
            current: 1,
            perPage: 5,
        }
    },
    created() {
      // populate array
      for(var i = 1; i <= 100; i++){
        this.items.push(i)
      }
    },
    computed: {
      total() {
        return this.items.length
      },
      /*
        Filtered items that are shown in the table
      */
      paginatedItems() {
        let page_number = this.current-1
 
        return this.items.slice(page_number * this.perPage, (page_number + 1) * this.perPage);
        
      }
    },
    
}

Vue.config.devtools = false
Vue.config.productionTip = false

const app = new Vue(example)

app.$mount('#app')
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.materialdesignicons.com/2.0.46/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<!-- Buefy CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/buefy/dist/buefy.min.css">

<!-- Buefy JavaScript -->
<script src="https://unpkg.com/buefy/dist/buefy.min.js"></script>

<div id="app" class="container">

  <div v-for="(item, index) in paginatedItems">
    {{ item }}
  </div>

  <b-pagination
    :total="total"
    :current.sync="current"
    :per-page="perPage"
  >
  </b-pagination>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do a filter with that displays your first 5. When you click in the number of the page or next page and have a var with that value. 
The your filter will need to read that var and give you the right number or objects.

Example:
Page 1 -> 1 to 5
Page 2 -> 6 to 10 (2 = +5, 3= +10)

Your filter will update and show the new ones